# What is the name for this style of Beaming in Music Engraving?

Tags: theory, notation, engraving

This is a rough example of my engraving of beaming which I really like and takes time to produce, and I think looks very good.

[image: my engraving beaming]

This is an example from an old score that seems to represent standard music engraving (which I don't like as much).[image]

This is Henle Edition.
[image: Henle Edition]

The essence of the beaming in question is that the beam clings to the staff line. The beam does not **cross** a staff-space. Is this type of beaming called "Henle beaming" or "Henle house style"? Or is there any **more** history to this? I've looked into the resources I know and can't find anything.

I'd really like to understand if it's a product of 20th c. engraving (perhaps German scores) or does its history go further back? Any help, I'd really love to know.

Comment: The second measure of your engraving looks like the beams get too close to the note heads.

Comment: It's a case of if the noteheads in the 2nd measure are too close, then those two measures would then look too close to the Henle (which I only saw during posting not while engraving). I don't like the Henle stem length, find them too long. But thanks for opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No particular names for the different styles as far as I know.  You can refer to it as 'Henle house style' if you like (and if it IS unique to Henle).

For what it's worth, I prefer the 'standard' style, can tolerate the Henle, but feel yours makes some stems annoyingly short.

There's a lot to be said for learning to love the styles offered by your notation program!

Comment: @Lawrence I agree with you on readability of styles.

Comment: @Lawrence thanks for input, I don't think this style is unique to Henle, but think it's definitely German. Appreciate stem length advice and really surprised all the comments say this, though I'm well aware of the rules.

Answer (score 5):

By default Sibelius produces this output:

[image]

and by changing the Beaming settings:

[image]

you can get the appearance you want:

[image]

Sibelius does this without any manual tweaking of individual beam positions at all.

But I agree with the other comments that say the note stems look too short.

Also, the angle of the beam does impart some sense of the spread of the beamed notes. I'd sooner have those subtle visual clues retained, rather than making all the beams look the same. But that's only my opinion.

Comment: Very handy to know on Sibelius output. Beam settings are exactly as I understand. Appreciate your time taken. Thanks for advice.